# Link Go with arbitrary object files (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, go, nasm

I would like to make functions written in assembly available to my Go code. I have seen [methods for linking functions written in Go assembler's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460967/go-isnt-linking-my-assembly-undefined-external-function) or [linking object files using the gccgo toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951028/is-it-possible-to-include-inline-assembly-in-google-go-code).

However, ideally, I would like to be able to use NASM and the "gc" toolchain. I have been messing around with cgo/6g/6l, but had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use syso files as outlined in https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GcToolchainTricks, however there are next to no resources about it.