# How to write asm code "bsrl" in golang

Tags: go, assembly

I need to write some asm code in golang. I read this question [Is it possible to include inline assembly in Google Go code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951028/is-it-possible-to-include-inline-assembly-in-google-go-code), but not see how to write it. 
Could anyone help me? thanks.

```
asm ("bsrl %1, %0;"
           :"=r"(bits)            /* output */
           :"r"(value) );         /* input */
```

Comment: If you need exactly `brsl`, `math.bits.LeadingZeros` (since Go 1.9) already implements this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers on [the question you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951028/is-it-possible-to-include-inline-assembly-in-google-go-code) say it's *not* possible to use inline-asm in Go, with any syntax.  GNU C inline-asm syntax isn't going to help.

**But fortunately, you don't need inline asm for `bsr`** (which finds the bit-index of the highest set bit).  Go 1.9 has an intrinsic / built-in function for bitwise operations that are close enough that they should compile efficiently.

---

Use [`math.bits.LeadingZeros32`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#LeadingZeros32) to get `lzcnt(x)`, which is `31-bsr(x)` for non-zero `x`.  This may cost extra instructions, especially on CPUs which only support `bsr`, not [`lzcnt`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LZCNT.html) (e.g. Intel pre-Haswell).

**Or use [`Len32(x) - 1`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#Len32)**

`Len32(x)` returns the number of bits required to represent `x`.  It returns `0` for `x=0`, and presumably it returns `1` for `x=1`, so it's `bsr(x) + 1`, with defined behaviour for `0` (thus potentially costing extra instructions).  Hopefully `Len32(x) - 1` can compile directly to a `bsr`.

Of course, if what you really wanted was `lzcnt`, then use `LeadingZeros32` in the first place.

---

Note that [`bsr`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html) leaves the destination register unmodified for input = `0`.  Intel's docs only say with an undefined value, so compilers probably don't take advantage of this guarantee that AMD documents and Intel does provide in hardware.

At least in theory, though, `Len32(x) - 1` could compile to a single `bsr` instruction if the compiler can prove that `x` is non-zero.